# How do I reference photographs with a separate numbering system to figures in latex?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, numbering

I am writing a book, and would like to be able to have the photographs labelled with an independent numbering system to my figures.  In the text I would refer to, for example, figure X and separately to photograph X, so I want them to have different numbering systems, just as equations and figures do.  Is it possible to have a different \begin{figure} environment so that the numbering can be separated?

Comment: Welcome! Yes. Load the `float` package and define a new kind of float. Be aware that figures and photographs may not retain their order in the document because a later photo may float earlier than an earlier figure or vice-versa. If you want more help, please edit your question and provide code for a minimal but complete document which we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce your situation. The `mwe` package provides images you can use in place of your own photos and figures.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `memoir` class (which extends the `book` class) then try this (less any typos):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newfloat[chapter]{photo}{lop}{Photo}
\newlistof{listofphotos}{lop}{List of Photos}
\newlistentry{photo}{{lop}{0}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listofphotos
\chapter{First}
Text
\begin{figure}
\centering
A FIGURE
\caption{A figure} \label{afig}
\end{figure}
\begin{photo}
\centering
A PICTURE
\caption{A photograph} \label{aphoto}
\end{photo}

Figure \ref{afig} is a figure while \ref{aphoto} is a photo.

\end{document}
```

The gory details of the above can be found in the `memoir` documentation (`> texdoc memoir`)  chapter 10.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using the `memoir` class, you can use the `float` package to achieve the same aims, but with a slightly different set of commands:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{float}
% Define a new float type for photos
\newfloat{photo}{htbp}{lop}[chapter]
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
% add the list of photos
\listof{photo}{List of Photos}
\chapter{First}
Text
\begin{figure}
\centering
A FIGURE
\caption{A figure} \label{afig}
\end{figure}
\begin{photo}
\centering
A PICTURE
\caption{A photograph} \label{aphoto}
\end{photo}

Figure \ref{afig} is a figure while \ref{aphoto} is a photo.

\end{document}
```