# have different caption for images and figures

Tags: captions

I need help in the following: inside my book I have images (basically photographs) and figures (results of mathematical calculations), in the epigraph in all cases appears the figure legend. What I'm after is that in the epigraphs of the images the legend appears: image 0.0 (where 0.0 is the chapter and image number).

Example:

Figure 1.1 blah blah blah

Image 1.1 blah blah blah

Figure 1.2 blah blah blah

Comment: Do you want a list of figures?

Comment: I do not need to make an index, what I'm looking for is that the epigraphs differentiate images of figures.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412974/how-do-i-reference-photographs-with-a-separate-numbering-system-to-figures-in-la